# Python: List as a key in dictionary -

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to read multiple files with very similar data. Each line of this data has a accessor_key and a value assosciated with it. I am trying to create a dictionary with the accessor_key as the dictionary key and as the dictionary value - a list of all the values read so far.

My code looks like this:

```
with open(ind_file, "r") as r:
  for line in r:
    nline = line.strip()
    spl = nline.split(",")
    if agg_d.has_key(spl[0]):

      key = spl[0]
      val = spl[1]
      dummy = agg_d[key]
      dummy.append(val)
      agg_d[key] = dummy
      print key, agg_d[key]

    else:
      print "Something is wrong"
      print agg_d
      print spl[0]
      print spl[1]
```

As you can see I want the value to get bigger every time, (the list increases in size by 1 every iteration) and store it back to the dictionary. 
However when I run this program, all keys in the dictionary take on the value of the list.

So for example in the beginning of the program the dictionary is :

```
agg_d = {'some_key': [], 'another_key': []}
```

After running it once it becomes:

```
agg_d = {'some_key': ['1'], 'another_key': ['1']}
```

When it should be just:

```
agg_d = {'some_key': ['1'], 'another_key': []}
```

EDIT: I found the work around I was looking for. I simply did:

```
with open(ind_file, "r") as r:
for line in r:
  nline = line.strip()
  spl = nline.split(",")
  if agg_d.has_key(spl[0]):

    key = spl[0]
    val = spl[1]
    dummy = agg_d[key]
    ad = dummy[:]
    ad.append(val)
    agg_d[key] = ad
    print key, agg_d[key]

  else:
    print "Something is wrong"
    print agg_d
    print spl[0]
    print spl[1]
```

But I would still like to know why this is happening at all. Is 'dummy' referenced to all the values of the dictionary? I am running this with Python 2.7.

Comment: show how you create empty dictionary. probably you assign the same empty list to both keys.

Comment: Sidenote: `dict.has_key` is deprecated and slower than the simpler common method for checking if a key is in a `dict`; change `if agg_d.has_key(spl[0]):` to `if spl[0] in agg_d:` which does the same thing fast and more Pythonically to boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `agg_d` is already initialised with your expected keys. You don't show how this is done, but I'm guessing that all of the initial values are in fact the *same list* - to which you append values in the code above.

If you initialise `agg_d` with a new list per key, then the problem should go away. You may be able to do this with a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> agg_d = {k:[] for k in keys}
>>> agg_d["a"].append(1)
>>> agg_d
{'a': [1], 'c': [], 'b': []}
```

Alternatively, depending on your needs, you could initialise each entry on demand as you encounter each key when reading the file.

Your workaround works because it replaces the original list with a new list and removes the shared reference.

Comment: Yes that is what I had suspected. I have initialized only one list for all the variables.

Answer (score 2):

> Is 'dummy' referenced to all the values of the dictionary? I am running this with Python 2.7.

Yes.  You've added a reference to the list, and there can be multiple references to that same list as you have observed. To illustrate this simply, try this:

```
dummy = [1,2,3]          # creates a list object and assigns reference to the name 'dummy'
d = dict()
d['some key'] = dummy    # creates the key 'some key' in the dictionary and assigns its value as the reference to the name 'dummy'

dummy.append(4)          # mutates the list referred to by name 'dummy'
                         # at this point, all references to that object have mutated similarly

print d['some key']
```

You will observe the following output:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4]
```

Your workaround is OK, but you could improve:

```
with open(ind_file, "r") as r:
    for line in r:
      spl = line.strip().split(",")
      key, val = spl[0], spl[1]
      if key in agg_d:
        agg_d[key] = agg_d[key][:].append(val)
        print key, agg_d[key]
      else:
        print "Something is wrong"
        print agg_d
        print spl[0]
        print spl[1]

agg_d[key] = agg_d[key][:].append(val)
```

This does not mutate your `dummy` list in place, and reassigns the value to the dictionary. Also avoids some unnecessary variables like `nline` and `ad` and `dummy`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that by default Python just adds a reference to the list as the dict value, not the list itself. So dict values are actually the bunch of pointers to the same object. You need to explicitly copy the list using either dummy[:] as you suggest in comment, or copy.deepcopy() to be more explicit.